# rebind default keybinding tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am adding a keybinding to my window a `Tk()` which contains :

```python
root.bind("Control-y", redo)
```

The problem is that it seems that <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> is bound by default to paste.

1. How can I rebind this?
2. I didn't find anywhere a list of the default keybindings of the widgets - they are available somewhere?

Comment: Are you aware that if your custom binding returns the string "return", built-in bindings won't do anything?

Comment: It's doubtful that control-y would be default for paste. because that's usually control-v.